# The named parameter 'body' isn't defined

Tags: android-studio, flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to create two screens in flutter to navigate from one screen to another. I created a body:raised button in the first screen but the error is saying 'the named parameter body isnt defined.'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzULX.png)

Comment: Please instead of posting pictures, paste your code into your question in a code block.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the [first linked picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seOrJ.png):
You are trying to set the `child` property outside of the `Center` widget.
The `Center` widget ends there where the `// Center` is behind the round bracket.

## Update

To place the `RaisedButton` below the `Container`, you have to use a [Column](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html). The `Column` has a parameter `children` which takes an array. There you place first your `Container` which includes the Image and the Text and second your `RaisedButton`.

```
body: Column(
   children: [
      Container(...),
      RaisedButton(...)
   ]
)
```

For next time when you share your code. Ether place it directly in your question, [like described here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) or use GitHub gists, [like described here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/writing-on-github/creating-gists).

Comment: so i corrected my code and added that child property inside the Center widget but now the error is saying ' The argument for the named parameter child was already specified.

Comment: yes, because you have already set the `child` property. I don't really know what you want to achieve with a second `child` in your `Center` widget. This is why I cannot completely say you how to solve your issue :/

Comment: to be precised, i want to create a simple raised button widget to navigate to second screen , initially i made this code(below) but when i got the error i tried to do mysterious things like wrapping raised inside container and creating child property multiple times inside centre which i dont want to do u can see i have changed the question and updated the image.

Comment: And you want to have this button below your `Container` which contains the image and the text? Or where? Can you please include your code into the question. Its way easier to read and to change as with the screenshot.

Comment: Exactly sir i want to have this raised button below my container which contains text and image. let me send u full code too.

Comment: i am actually having problem to insert full code here, is there any alternative way so that i can send you full code?  Your Email or something?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to add a `child` inside a `Scaffold`.
Scaffold only has a `body` attribute. Please make the `Center` is inside the the `body`.

Comment: so i corrected my code and added that child property inside the Center widget but now the error is saying ' The argument for the named parameter child was already specified.

Answer (score -1):

Just run flutter upgrade. That's all

Comment: I think it's not related to flutter version. The Center widget doesn't have body property, use child. And if author want both Container and RaisedButton, he should add them to `children` in `Column` widget